# How to test data polling on AngularJS with Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have trouble to test data polling in my controller

Controller logic looks like this

```
$onInit() {
  this.requestRootLocations();
  this.startDataPolling();
}

private startDataPolling() {

  this.stop = this.$interval(() =>
    this.requestRootLocations()
    , this.DATA_POLLING_INTERVAL);
}

private requestRootLocations() {
      this.locationsService.requestRootElements().then(function (locationItem) {
        ...

        this.entityList = (locationItem["locations"] instanceof Array) ? locationItem["locations"] : [];
      }.bind(this), function () {
        console.log("Error on loading locations data.");
      });
    }
```

**Update:**
The http request in the service:

```
public requestRootElements() {
      return this.$http.get(this.API + "locations").then((response) => response.data);
    }
```

This works fine like expected.

The test case looks like this

```
it("should call http request on intervals", function () {

  ctrl.$onInit();
  $httpBackend.whenGET(api + "locations").respond(200, locationData);

  // advance in time by 1 seconds
  $interval.flush(1000);

  $httpBackend.expectGET(api + "locations");
  // after 1 seconds locations should be called once
  $httpBackend.flush();

  expect(ctrl.counts.length).toBe(4);
  expect(ctrl.entities.length).toBe(6);

  $interval.flush(dataPollingInterval);
  $httpBackend.expectGET(api + "locations"); //does not work, why?
  $httpBackend.flush();

  // after the second call the data should be the same in this case
  expect(ctrl.counts.length).toBe(4);
  expect(ctrl.entities.length).toBe(6);
});
```

But on the second expectGET is an error

> Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET /apiv1/locations

Comment: Where are these $http requests? Posting truncated snippets of code doesn't help. If this happens in a controller, please, post it entirely. If this happens in a service, please, post both a controller and a service.

Comment: Thank you, i have updated the question

Comment: Still not sure why it fails. It's not obvious that DATA_POLLING_INTERVAL is 1000, for starters. The real problem is that several units are mixed into one integration test and it is not very effective. It introduces too many moving parts and doesn't test anything that couldn't be tested in isolation at the same time. See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the units aren't isolated. This is integration test (controller + service + $interval), not unit test. When a test becomes red, it's not possible to say which of the units has failed.

The proper strategy to unit-test this is to mock everything but tested unit (controller). `$interval` can be optionally mocked too, and we don't really need to test how it works - this was already tested by Angular.

```
constructor(...) {
  ...
  // bind callback method
  this.dataPollingHandler = this.dataPollingHandler.bind(this);
}

$onInit() {
  this.requestRootLocations();
  this.stop = this.$interval(this.dataPollingHandler, this.DATA_POLLING_INTERVAL);
}

private dataPollingHandler() {
  this.requestRootLocations()
}
```

And it can be tested like

```
spyOn(ctrl, 'requestRootLocations');

// unbind callback method
ctrl.dataPollingHandler.call(null);

expect(ctrl.requestRootLocations).toHaveBeenCalled();

...

var intervalPromise = $q.resolve();
var intervalMock = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(intervalPromise);
var ctrl = $controller(..., { $interval: intervalMock });

ctrl.$onInit();
expect(ctrl.stop).toBe(intervalPromise);
expect($intervalStub).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ctrl.dataPollingHandler, 1000);

...

var locationsServiceMock = {
  requestRootLocations: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue($q.resolve(locationData));
}

var ctrl = $controller(..., { locationsService: locationsServiceMock });
// now ctrl.requestRootLocations can be tested
...
```

It is ok to have both unit and integration tests in the suite, but when proper controller and service unit tests exist, integration test becomes redundant.

Comment: you are totally right. But this ist not the answer i hoped to get. It is an integration test and after hours or trying i got it running:
    
    $httpBackend.expectGET(api + "locations");
    $interval.flush(1000);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(ctrl.isEditing).toBe(false);

    // after first intervall one request should be called
    $httpBackend.expectGET(api + "locations");
    $interval.flush(dataPollingInterval);
    $httpBackend.flush();

Comment: Glad it works for you, putting interval flush after backend expect makes sense. But as it was said, it makes no sense to test $interval like that. It was already tested by Angular and you can be sure that it works as expected. This kind of integration tests usually shouldn't be written because they can't replace unit tests and don't benefit the coverage.

Comment: Hopes this helps. It's not always clear if the asker expects to get an answer to 'how to test...' or just a fix for the bug.